# tslint: benefit of "object-literal-shorthand"

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint

an example for this rule:

```
    this.http.post(this.apiUrl + "screenshot", {
        url: url,
        ratio: ratio
    }).subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
    });
```

tslint will complain about this code. the way tslint wants me to do this would be

```
    this.http.post(this.apiUrl + "screenshot", {
        url,
        ratio
    }).subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
    });
```

for me the first snippet is way more well-arranged. I disabled the corresponding rule but now I wonder if there is any benefit of using the "object-literal-shorthand" in terms of performance or something else.

I think this gets pretty messy, especially if the literal is bigger and mixed with variables that can't use the shorthand. So whats the reason for this rule, I don't get it.

Comment: There is no performance advantage. Both are strictly equivalent. I guess the rule allows 1. to make you aware of this shorthand syntax 2. to promote consistency in naming by encouraging you to use this shorthand syntax: I hate it when I see `{ firstName: first_name, date: time, url: URL }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the *fixable* rules in tslint.

https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/cli/

When you run:

```
tslint --fix
```

It will rewrite the code to use literal syntax.

> benefit of using the "object-literal-shorthand" in terms of performance

The rule is part of a collection of *shorter code fragment* rules that help produce fewer lines of code.

> So whats the reason for this rule, I don't get it.

Fixable rules in tslint are intended to assist with code sharing. You can add a Git hook or a build stage that will run `tslint --fix` automatically for you.

People who use modern IDEs that display tslint warnings don't really benefit from the fixable feature. The IDE bugs you to fix it when you write it.

Just turn off if you don't want it on.